# How to say "See Naples and Die" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am not a student of Latin; I merely wish to give my short story a Latin title, namely the Latin translation of "See Naples and Die." The best I could find, not understanding Latin grammar, is "Videre Neapolis ac Morior." If that's incorrect, can you please correct it for me? Thank you. (I chose "ac" because of the close relationship between Naples and death in my narrative.)

Comment: Can you explain more about what the grammar is doing in the title? Are you issuing someone commands? Multiple people commands? Is it more of an infinitive phrase (e.g. "to see Naples and die is the best adventure")?

Answer (score 14):

*See Naples and die* is a saying which became internationally known after J.W. Goethe mentioned it in his *Italian Journey* (vol. I, entry for March 2nd, 1787). Goethe quotes it in Italian *(Vedi Napoli e poi muori!)* and then translates it into German *(Siehe Neapel und stirb!).* The English version is a literal translation of the German one, but the problem is that the ambiguity of the original Italian was completely lost in the process. Furthermore, while in Italian and German the verbs refer undisputably to a singular subject, in English *see* and *die* could refer to plural subjects, which is a different ambiguity.

Few Italians would approve of the exclamation mark used by Goethe. True, *vedi* and *muori* **might** be imperatives, as Goethe understood them, but they might also be second-person indicatives, as in *you see Naples and you die.* Even if they are imperatives, they are not orders: the meaning is *don’t die before seeing Naples;* if they are indicatives, the meaning is either *the sight of Naples makes you die of wonder* or *after seeing Naples you can happily die (because you will never see anything more beautiful).* In fact, it is an ambiguous sentence and even native speakers of Italian like me are unsure. I tend to prefer the last interpretation, but I accept that the first two are completely legitimate. Everybody agrees that the general meaning is that the sight of Naples is a life-changing experience. (The racist interpretation *if you visit Naples you will be killed by organized crime* pops up sometimes in stand-up comedies, but is only a bad-taste joke.)

That said, let’s try a Latin translation. Italian uses *e poi* ( = *and then* ) to bind the two verbs; Goethe forgot to translate *poi* ( = *then* ) but it is important, because it places the second action explicitly *after* the first one. In Latin, a good way to express precedence in time is a costruction called *ablativus absolutus,* which doesn’t use a finite verb and gives us *Neapolī conspectā* for the first part. The verb to use can be chosen among many. My preference is for *conspicio,* which combines vision with emotional experience. For the second part, in my opinion a future tense could convey all three possible meanings of the Italian original. So my proposal is

*Neapolī conspectā moriēris*

It can be translated back as *you will die after seeing Naples.* At least, it sounds Latin and has a certain gravity.

Comment: "precedence in time is not expressed by a finite verb" -- well, this is just wrong, words like *deinde* and temporal clauses exist, no? (By the way, it's the *ablativus*, sc. *casus*.)

Comment: You are right on both counts. Corrected. However, do you agree with me that an _ablativus absolutus_ is the best solution solution in such a short sentence?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of the phrase but I'm not sure the choice of the future tense is the best way to capture it -- the Latin sentence sounds to me more like a prediction or prophecy.

Comment: I wrote my answer in order to provide a detailed analysis of the original Italian. The translation is the best I can come up with, but I agree it has shortcomings and I will be happy to upvote better translations if anybody provides them. The actual meanings of _conspicio_ and the uses of future tense in Latin deserve separate questions. I’ll probably post them myself in the following days.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the future tense is a bad choice.  Doesn't a prophecy/instruction/warning best capture the ambiguity of the Italian by obscuring whether this is an instruction or a prophetic warning?

Comment: Another option for the translation of "die"/"muori" might be using the present subjunctive to indicate a command to an indefinite second person.  This might also carry some useful ambiguity, since the subjunctive might also be one of the other kinds, such as possibility.  I think the form could be along the lines of Neapolī vīsā moriāre.  Using vīsā also might give some useful ambiguity, since it could be the participle corresponding to vīdeō or vīsō and thus perhaps more fully capture the possible range of meanings of "vedi."

Comment: @Vegawatcher The future is bad because the Italian is neither an instruction nor a prophetic warning.— *vīsā* is of course the best unmarked translation but there is no ambiguity because the causative *vīsere* has no past participle of its own, it simply means *vīsum facere* 'to go see,' a factitive 'see,' the resulting state being the same old *vīsus* 'seen', not something like 'having been seen by going to see'.

Comment: As a reminder, remember to be respectful of others even if you disagree. Let's keep comments civil, please.